# Why didn't Starfleet know about the Borg prior to the events of "Q-Who"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-generations

I have finally binged *Star Trek: TNG* and the movie series together so something stuck out for me so I apologize if this had been answered in a novelization or somewhere outside the TV series. In TNG the Federation met the Borg in "Q-Who" but in the beginning of *Star Trek Generations* Guinan and the rest of the El-Aurian were being sent to Earth (after what I think is the Borg attack on their world). When Guinan is rescued it was  2293, so wouldn't the El-Aurian people have told Starfleet about the Borg 80 years before the start of the series?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/DaystromInstitute/comments/28rgg9/guinan_what_do_we_really_know_about_her_almost/ might have some useful data.

Comment: Also https://www.reddit.com/r/DaystromInstitute/comments/2hnhfv/captain_picard_knew_about_the_borg_long_before/, although they seem to be much more speculative. TL;DR, there's a good chance that humanity has known about the Borg, but it's been highly classified.

Comment: Technically, in the movie Star Trek: First Contact, Lily Sloane, Cochrane's assistant, witnessed Captain Picard kill some of the Borg on board the Enterprise E. That happened on April 5, 2063. Unless Lily was sworn to secrecy, she would have likely have recorded what she witnessed and Starfleet in the 21st Century would likely have had this information.

Comment: Sure but the word of a bunch of refugees about a big bad that lives **half a galaxy away** is basically of little/no interest other than to galactic anthropology buffs.

Comment: Starfleet kinda knew already about the Borg but wouldn't have known their name. The Enterprise (NX-01) encountered the Borg (iirc the Borg they encountered were survivors from the Borg that the Enterprise E encountered during the events of First Contact)